# What is the name for the top part of an HTTP message?

Tags: http, http-headers

I've been trying to think of the proper name for the top part of an HTTP message, which includes the request line and the headers. "Headers" doesn't quite cut it because of the request line and "request" doesn't work because that would include the body as well.

Can somebody please enlighten me? :(

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it. There's the request line, the request headers, and the request body.

Answer (score 1):

Can be HTTP request headers in the following format:

```
GET /tutorials/other/top-20-mysql-best-practices/ HTTP/1.1
Host: net.tutsplus.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=r2t5uvjq435r4q7ib3vtdjq120
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Could also be HTTP response header in the following format:

```
HTTP/1.x 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 04:36:25 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: W3 Total Cache/0.8
Pragma: public
Expires: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 05:36:25 GMT
Etag: "pub1259380237;gz"
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Nov 2009 03:50:37 GMT
X-Pingback: http://net.tutsplus.com/xmlrpc.php
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie, User-Agent
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Mate, take a look. I thing that there no other valid answers. TonyGW is correct.

Is an screenshot from "Head First Servlets and JSP 2nd Edition"

[image]